# How do I get my webcam to work

Tags: 14.04

I have a built in webcam I have a Asus Eee.  I would like to know how to get it to work I am new to Ubuntu  I have Ubuntu 24.o4 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Running `cheese` on your terminal will bring up your webcam if you have `cheese` installed.

To find out if you have `cheese` installed, type the following in your terminal:

`which cheese`

If `cheese` is installed, you should see the path to your `cheese` installation- something like `/usr/bin/cheese`.

But if you don't have `cheese` installed, simply install it by doing:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install cheese`

Now that you have `cheese` installed, enter the `cheese` command on your terminal to bring up your webcam:

`cheese`

Enjoy!